# Returning a value from a child function inside the main function using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know if i made my self clear with that tile, i think it is confusing, but let me explain.
So i have that js code:

```
function validateUserLogin() {
  'use strict';
  var xmlhttp, url = '../controller.php?action=validatelogin',
  email = document.getElementById('email').value,
  password = document.getElementById('password').value;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
  } else {
      alert('Your browser does not support XMLHTTP!');
  }
  xmlhttp.open('POST', url, true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  xmlhttp.send('email=' + email + '&password=' + password);
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
          if (xmlhttp.responseText === 'Error1') {
              $('#email').css('border', '1px solid red');
              //A value to return
          }
          if (xmlhttp.responseText === 'Error2') {
              $('#email').css('border', '1px solid green');
              $('#password').css('border', '1px solid red');
              //A value to return
          }
      }
  };
  //I want it here
}
```

In the code above i have a function for validating a user when he tries to login sending ajax requests. On the server-side script i echo a message when either email or password aren't correct and i change the input's border color to green or red. So far so good. All i want is to return a variable from the 2 ifs i have inside the child function to the validateUserLogin and then return a true or false to the login form. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a previously declared var? (`stored` here)

You can use `xmlhttp.open('POST', url, false);` to send as a synchronous request.

I replaced your `.onreadystatechange` by a load listener, works for me on this Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/1ma3svcd/
The PHP file called simply returns 'Error1'.

```
var xmlhttp;

function validateUserLogin() {
  'use strict';
  var stored;
  var url = 'https://zenoo.fr/testAjax.php',
  email = 'test@test.tes',
  password = 'testMe';
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
  } else {
      alert('Your browser does not support XMLHTTP!');
  }

  xmlhttp.addEventListener("load", transferComplete, false);
  xmlhttp.open('POST', url, false);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  xmlhttp.send('email=' + email + '&password=' + password);
}

function transferComplete(){
      if (xmlhttp.responseText === 'Error1') {
        $('#email').css('border', '1px solid red');
        stored=true;
      }
      if (xmlhttp.responseText === 'Error2') {
        $('#email').css('border', '1px solid green');
        $('#password').css('border', '1px solid red');
        stored=false;
      }

      console.log(stored);
}


validateUserLogin();
```

Comment: You can use the second parameter from .open to get a synchronous call : `xmlhttp.open('POST', url, false);`

Comment: still undefined

Comment: I confused the .open and .send function. Try setting false with the .open() function.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible because the HttpRequest is async. meaning your function won't wait for the Request to complete before it returns a value.

I don't know what you're trying to achieve here but i suspect that the method `validateUserLogin()` is being used inside a form's `onsubmit` handler.

If that is the case, then i will suggest you use an event listener instead

ex:

```
var form = document.getElementById('login-form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    // Prevent form from loading the page (submit)
    e.preventDefault();

    // Then call your function here
    // If user was logged in without errors,
    // You can use in your function "window.location.href = 'http://mywebapp.dev/dashboard'"
    validateLogin();
});
```

Comment: Glad i could be of help.

Answer (score -1):

@Zenoo answer doesn't work because you can't: Ajax is asynchronous, meaning that when you arrive at last line ("//I want it there") the browser probably hasn't already sent the Ajax request.

You could pass a callback function

Comment: Even if you could, @John is implementing it in an Asynchronous way

Comment: Yes @John, I mean a callback function to be passed to onreadystatechange